# How do I populate values of an JSON object data into a selectbox?

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter-3

> when using this code selectbox option value data populate as UNDEFINED..

```
var obj =  jQuery.parseJSON('['+<?= $customers_json; ?>+']') ;
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++)
{
html_code += '<option value="'+myJSON[id].toString()+'">'+myJSON.toString()+'</option>';
}
```

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id,name FROM customers";
    $customerResult = $conn->query($sql2);
    //$customers123 = $customerResult->fetch_assoc();
     while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customerResult)) {
      $rows[] = $r;
  }

 $customers123=json_encode($rows);
 $customers_json =  $customers123;
```

Comment: add output of `echo $customers_json;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myJSON = jQuery.parseJSON('['+"[{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"sooraj\"},{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"ravi pillai\"},{\"id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"jasil\"},{\"id\":\"6\",\"name\":\"athul\"},{\"id\":\"7\",\"name\":\"dheeraj123\"}]"+']') ; 
myJSON =myJSON[0];

let html_code ='';

for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++)
{
   html_code += '<option value="'+myJSON[i]['id']+'">'+myJSON[i]['name']+'</option>';
}

console.log(html_code);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For loop will be

```
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++)
{
   html_code += '<option value="'+myJSON[i]['id'].toString()+'">'+myJSON[i]['name'].toString()+'</option>';
}
```

Comment: var myJSON =  jQuery.parseJSON('['+"[{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"sooraj\"},{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"ravi pillai\"},{\"id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"jasil\"},{\"id\":\"6\",\"name\":\"athul\"},{\"id\":\"7\",\"name\":\"dheeraj123\"}]"+']') ;

for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++)
{
   html_code += '<option value="'+myJSON[i]['id'].toString()+'">'+myJSON[i]['name'].toString()+'</option>';
}

Comment: @soorajsubramanyan main array under another array so need to make `myJSON =myJSON[0];`. I have updated my Answer.

Comment: thank you soo much ..its working ...how can we make it to single array..

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to use for and in. Its a good way of traversing an object:

```
var obj =  jQuery.parseJSON('['+<?= $customers_json; ?>+']');

obj = obj[0][0]; // to account for position within object

for (key in obj)
{
html_code += '<option value="'+key+'">'+obj[key]+'</option>';
}
```

Bear in mind you may need to remove all the previous options before adding more :o)

Comment: when i add this ..select box value like [object object],[object object ]

Comment: What Json are you returning (can you supply an example)? I had this yesterday on my own code and I had done array(array('name'=>'value')) which means I needed to start at position [0].

Comment: my json data alert :  [[{"id":"2","name":"sooraj"},{"id":"4","name":"ravi pillai"},{"id":"5","name":"jasil"},{"id":"6","name":"athul"},{"id":"7","name":"dheeraj123"}]]

Comment: Try the change to obj.